# Dao in Usecase. MVVM or Clean Architecture anti-pattern?

Tags: android, mvvm, clean-architecture, anti-patterns

In our "SearchUsecase" we have access to "ShowFtsDao" directly.

Does it violate the Clean Architecture principles? Does it violate the MVVM architecture?

Assuming our intention is to develop a well-built, standard structure, is there anything wrong with this piece of code?

```
class SearchUsecase @Inject constructor(
    private val searchRepository: SearchRepository,
    private val showFtsDao: ShowFtsDao,
    private val dispatchers: AppCoroutineDispatchers
) : SuspendingWorkInteractor<SearchShows.Params, List<ShowDetailed>>() {
    override suspend fun doWork(params: Params): List<ShowDetailed> {
        return withContext(dispatchers.io) {
            val remoteResults = searchRepository.search(params.query)
            if (remoteResults.isNotEmpty()) {
                remoteResults
            } else {
                when {
                    params.query.isNotBlank() -> showFtsDao.search("*$params.query*")
                    else -> emptyList()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    data class Params(val query: String)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does.

Because your `domain` module has access to the `data` module and actually you've violated the **dependency rule**.

> That rule specifies that something declared in an outer circle must
> not be mentioned in the code by an inner circle.

`Domain` layer must contain interfaces for details (Repositories) which are implemented in the `data` layer,

and then, they could be injected into the `UseCase`s (DIP).

Answer (score 0):

I believe your use case handles more logic than it needs to.
As a simple explanation I like to think about the components this way:

- **Sources**:  RemoteSource (networking), LocalSource (db), optionally MemorySource are an abstraction over your database and networking api and they do the IO thread switching & data mapping (which comes in handy on big projects, where the backend is not exactly mobile driven)
- **Repository**: communicates with the sources, he is responsible for deciding where do you get the data from. I believe in your case if the RemoteSource returns empty data, then you get it from the LocalSource. (you can expose of course different methods like `get()` or `fetch()`, where the consumer specifies if it wants the latest data and based on that the repository calls the correct Source.
- **UseCases**: Talk with multiple repositories and combine their data.